# Choose one particular element from two separate lists

Tags: java, webdriver

Could someone, please, assist in following case:
Namely, have to pickup one country from the list and one league form second list.
***Tried with AND function, but in Selenium it throws error as non-existing element, while found as a two separate lists as shown below***

List of countries:

```
List<WebElement> chosenCountry = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//body//be-list[contains(@class, 'ng-star-inserted')]/ul//li/div/span/h4/img"));
    for (int i = 0; i < chosenCountry.size(); i++) {
        // System.out.println(chosenCountry.get(i).getAttribute("title"));
        String country = chosenCountry.get(i).getAttribute("title");
    }
```

which looks like:

```
Argentina
Brazil
Chile
Colombia
England
India
International
Iran
Jamaica
Kuwait
Mexico
Scotland
```

List of Leagues:

```
List<WebElement> chosenLeague = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//body//be-list[contains(@class, 'ng-star-inserted')]/ul//li/div/span"));
    for (int k = 0; k < chosenLeague.size(); k++) {
        // System.out.println(chosenLeague.get(k).getText());
        String league = chosenLeague.get(k).getText();
    }
```

which looks like:

```
Primera B Metropolitana
Primera C
Superliga
Paulista A2
State Leagues
Primera B
Primera Division
Championship
League 1
League 2
National League
```

Note, that those data are dynamical ones, so it is useless to pickup needed element from **get(i)**.

Tried with if clause without success:

```
if ( chosenCountry.get(i).getAttribute("title").equals("England)||chosenLeague.get(k).getText().equals("Championship") {
```

It throws error and not giving me any option.
Where do I making mistake?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you miss a quotation in your if statement.

this:

```
if ( chosenCountry.get(i).getAttribute("title").equals("England)||chosenLeague.get(k).getText().equals("Championship") {
```

should look like this:

```
if ( chosenCountry.get(i).getAttribute("title").equals("England")||chosenLeague.get(k).getText().equals("Championship") {
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not noticed that. What a silly error